# How to import uncommented text from a file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, import

I am trying to import data from multiple files that have different commented header rows. But while importing it should import only the uncommented text from the file. How can this be done with Python?

**UPDATE**

Data is of the form:

```
#===========================
# Lorem ipsum
#===========================
#
# A
# B
# C
# D
#
#---------------------------
# Data
#---------------------------
#
# 1
# 2.
# 3.
# 4.
75  123
76  168
77  345
78  454
```

At present I am importing using numpy loadtxt:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', skiprows=17, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
```

But the commented rows is different in different files, I have to import more than 5000 files. Every time skip rows is not 17.

Comment: Could you give a short example how your data looks like ? What have you tried so far

Comment: There is a `comment` param you can pass to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) but we really need to an example of the raw data to advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the situation correctly, but here goes.
Knowing the exact way the commented lines start (e.g. '--comment--')...
This should work (for each file of data):

```
imported_lines = []
comment_start = '--comment--'
file_list = ['path/to/file1','path/to/file2','path/to/fileN']
for file_path in file_list:
    data_file = open(file_path,'r')
    for line in data_file.readlines():
        if line[:len(comment_start)]==comment_start:
            continue
        imported_lines.append(line)
    data_file.close()
```

EDIT: In your case, you should set comment_start to '#' or simply change

```
if line[:len(comment_start)]==comment_start:
```

to

```
if line.startswit('#'):
```

EDIT2: numpy.loadtxt has the default setting comment='#', which skips lines starting with '#'. You should change your import line to

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', delimiter='\t', unpack=True, comments='#')
```

(To specify comments='#' is not strictly necessary because it's set by default)

Answer (score 1):

This can be loaded using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) by passing param `comment='#'`:

```
In [450]:

temp='''#===========================
# Lorem ipsum
#===========================
#
# A
# B
# C
# D
#
#---------------------------
# Data
#---------------------------
#
# 1
# 2.
# 3.
# 4.
75  123
76  168
77  345
78  454'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+',comment='#', header=None)
df
Out[450]:
    0    1
0  75  123
1  76  168
2  77  345
3  78  454
```

Answer (score 0):

For each file run this function:

```
def code_start(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for i, line in enumerate(fh.readlines()):
            if not len(line): continue
            if not line[0] is '#': return i
        return 0
```

With your sample-file this results in `17`. It returns the amount of rows to skip, when no comments where found it returns `0` instead.

```
code_start('your_file.txt')
>>> 17
```